# Bootstrap Popover with Dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to stick a dropdown inside a popover (both bootstrap), and it 'sort of' works. The first popover I open works fine, but as soon as I open another one (from a different image) it stops working (take a look at [this video](http://screencast.com/t/ukFqu8bj) to see what I mean).

In my HTML I'm making sure every dropdown has a different IDs (by binding my object ID, which is always different) since apparently that's what Bootstrap uses:

```
<div class="dropdown collection-selection-view">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle collection-dropdown" type="button" id="collection-dropdown-<%- id %>" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose or Create Collection
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu user-collection-list" aria-labelledby="collection-dropdown-<%- id %>"></ul>
</div>
```

And they render with unique IDs alright.

Example #1:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle collection-dropdown" type="button" id="collection-dropdown-40261" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose or Create Collection
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu user-collection-list" aria-labelledby="collection-dropdown-40261">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Happy collection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sad collection</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example #2:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle collection-dropdown" type="button" id="collection-dropdown-39935" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose or Create Collection
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu user-collection-list" aria-labelledby="collection-dropdown-39935">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Happy collection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sad collection</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But for some reason it still doesn't work... any ideas of what could be going on?

Comment: The issue is probably in your JavaScript or in some HTML that's not in your question. Can you add that? As it is, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works ok for me as well [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/kk29usL2/1/).
Try to set up a nonworking example

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Ok, I was able to isolate the problem, here's the whole project, just run index.html once you download the zip file. Thank you!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TCEp0dTZ-oUVBZZExTV0x2TXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @paulitto That is really interesting. I just pasted a comment where I isolated the problem and it still happens to me, here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TCEp0dTZ-oUVBZZExTV0x2TXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok,.. the problem is that $(document).off('click') I have in the 'shown.bs.popover' event handler. I was trying to stop listening to the click event to stop running that function, but I guess that's not the way to go...

Comment: It does seem that `$(document).off('click')` is causing the problem. What is that trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JoshuaDwire I was just trying to unsubscribe from the click event that I have there, but I never though it would cause such side effect. I just took the '.off' out and use the isPopoverOpen flag to determine if I should run the next of the code or not. Thanks for the help, and I'm probably gonna close / delete this question because it's way too specific to my mistake.